# How to find identical sequences in Python

Tags: python, sequences

I am new to Python, and i want to know how to find identical sequences from Fasta file in Python.
for example, here i have 4 record sequence reads, how to find the identical sequences and return their ids? Thank you very much!!

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record=list(SeqIO.parse("data/dna.txt", "fasta"))
for i in range(0,len(record)):
    print record[i].id,record[i].seq


seq1 GAATGCATACTGCATCGATA
seq2 CATAAAACGTCTCCATCGCT
seq3 TGCCCAAGTTGTGAAGTGTC
seq4 TGCCCAAGTTGTGAAGTGTC
```

Comment: what is the id here, seqx ?

Comment: Is the problem you don't know how to test if 2 sequences are equal, or how to go about searching all of the possible pairs, or something else?

Comment: To remove ambiguity, please show some (small) sample input and the desired output that corresponds to that specified input.

Comment: @sapam yes, it means seqx

Comment: @ScottHunter I guess my problem is how to search all of the possible pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the list of IDs per sequence using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like so:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict
records=list(SeqIO.parse("data/dna.txt", "fasta"))
compilation = defaultdict(list)
for record in records:
    compilation[record.seq].append(record.id)
```

Comment: +1 for `defaultdict()`. To print ids of identical sequences: `print("\n".join(map(", ".join, compilation.values())))`. You probably don't need to call `list()`. You could use `identical` name instead of `compilation`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with a `dict`.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
records = list(SeqIO.parse("data/dna.txt", "fasta"))
d = dict()
for record in records:
    if record.seq in d:
        d[record.seq].append(record)
    else:
        d[record.seq] = [record]
for seq, record_set in d.iteritems():
    print seq + ': (' + str(len(record_set)) + ')'
    for record in record_set:
        print '    ' + record.id
```

Prints like:

```
GAATGCATACTGCATCGATA: (1)
    seq1
CATAAAACGTCTCCATCGCT: (1)
    seq2
TGCCCAAGTTGTGAAGTGTC: (2)
    seq3
    seq4
```